# Swift JSON parsing

Tags: json, swift

I am working on an iOS weather app and need some help getting some values with JSON.  I am trying to pull the value of id in the weather object. I am getting a value of nil when I debug. Could someone please help me with the logic? Here is the JSON request and Swift code.

```
{
    "coord":{
        "lon":138.93,
        "lat":34.97
    },
    "weather":[
        {
            "id":800,
            "main":"Clear",
            "description":"clear sky",
            "icon":"01n"
        }
    ],
    "base":"cmc stations",
    "main":{
        "temp":292.181,
        "pressure":1005.21,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_min":292.181,
        "temp_max":292.181,
        "sea_level":1014.59,
        "grnd_level":1005.21
    },
    "wind":{
        "speed":3.41,
        "deg":78.0005
    },
    "clouds":{
        "all":0
    },
    "dt":1464801034,
    "sys":{
        "message":0.003,
        "country":"JP",
        "sunrise":1464723086,
        "sunset":1464774799
    },
    "id":1851632,
    "name":"Shuzenji",
    "cod":200
}
```

Here is my Swift snippet:

```
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=6361e893fa064b1bfeaca686cd0929cc")!
            let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    print("JSON Downloaded Sucessfully.")

                    do{

                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                        if let today = json["weather"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            //this is pulling 4 key value pairs
                            for weather in today {

                                let id = weather["id"] as? String


                                self.trumpDescription.text=id;
                                print(id)

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                    catch {
                        print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                    }

                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Please clean up that indentation :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this in your code:
`let id = weather["id"]?.stringValue`

instead of this:
`let id = weather["id"] as? String`

And see the magic!

**Edit for explanation**:
As this answer worked for you, let me tell you why it did.
The id is being sent as integer from the server side. When you do `weather["id"]` it returns object of type `AnyObject?`. When you do `weather["id"] as? String` the casting fails thus you were getting nil.

Comment: can u try swiftJSON? Daam easy!

Comment: With SwiftyJSON the code crashes because of the question mark (JSON objects are non-optional). But this is irrelevant because the OP doesn't use SwiftyJSON

Comment: I am just waiting for the person who has asked question to try my answer and give his feedback

Comment: Thank you so much The Rohan Sanap, worked ! THANK YOU!

Comment: do remove the downvote if possible as my answer is correct and accepted.

Comment: @TheRohanSanap do you have time to help me with another question. I am trying to parse the JSON for the temp in the same example as above. I got the id to work. The id is in a JSON array but the rest of the items are just objects. Can you possibly look at my logic and see where I went wrong? Here is my snippet://this is where I am confused it changes from an array to just an object
                            let temp = json["temp"] as? String
                            self.currentTempView.text=temp;
                            print(temp)

Comment: @RobBasso write the question for the same with proper formatting just like you did with this problem of yours. Plenty of people will be happy to help you and you will also gain some reputation for contributing to community.

Comment: @TheRohanSanap cool will do . I am still new to stack overflow. I appreciate your help and advice

Comment: @TheRohanSanap I just added the question. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617504/swift-and-json-parsing-only-an-object-not-an-array?noredirect=1#comment62717564_37617504

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your cast to a string. If you do not cast the id as a String, it will print "800" as an Int.

When you are grabbing the id from the json and converting it to a string, it reads the string and includes the new line character.

I played around in the playground

[image]

So you are correctly getting to the spot in the json, but you need to unwrap your optional.

Comment: Do you have time for another question, I am trying to parse another object "temp" in JSON. Same request. It is an object not an array.   Can you help me get the temp object
                            
                            //this is where I am confused it changes from an array to just an object
                            let temp = json["temp"] as? String
                            self.currentTempView.text=temp;
                            print(temp)
                        }

Comment: im not sure what you mean by it is an object not an array. Arrays are objects? I see you are casting it as a string, is it a String that you want?

Comment: I am sorry , I am learning. All I want to do is get the value for temp. the id object is in the wether array, but the other objects are not in an array they are just regular object. I do want the temp variable to be a string

Comment: i see a "temp" object in the "main" array. In which case you would use json["main"]["temp"]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) to unwrap optionals so you don't have to have a bunch of `if lets`:

`let id = weather["id"] as? String ?? ""`

Which will either set `id` to the value or to `""` if it doesn't exist.