# Swift and JSON parsing only an object not an array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am working on a weather app that parses JSON data and sets the text of my label to the temp value of the JSON request. I got the value of id from the weather object array, but the temp is not in an array it is just an object. Can someone please tell me where I am wrong. My value is reurning nil because I am not fetching it correctly. Here is my snippet and JSON.

```
@IBAction func getWeather(sender: AnyObject) {
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=MYAPPID")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("JSON Downloaded Sucessfully.")

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                    if let today = json["weather"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        //this is pulling 4 key value pairs
                        for weather in today {

                            //this works
                            let id = weather["id"]?.stringValue
                            self.trumpDescription.text=id;
                            print(id)

                            //this is where I am confused it changes from an array to just an object
                            let temp = json["temp"] as? String
                            self.currentTempView.text=temp;
                            print(temp)
                        }

                    }

                }

                catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }

            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }`
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "coord": {
    "lon": 138.93,
    "lat": 34.97
    },
    "weather": [
    {
    "id": 803,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "broken clouds",
    "icon": "04n"
    }
    ],
    "base": "cmc stations",
    "main": {
    "temp": 292.581,
    "pressure": 1019.48,
    "humidity": 99,
    "temp_min": 292.581,
    "temp_max": 292.581,
    "sea_level": 1028.92,
    "grnd_level": 1019.48
    },
    "wind": {
    "speed": 5.36,
    "deg": 237.505
    },
    "clouds": {
    "all": 64
    },
    "dt": 1464964606,
    "sys": {
    "message": 0.0037,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1464895855,
    "sunset": 1464947666
    },
    "id": 1851632,
    "name": "Shuzenji",
    "cod": 200
    }
```

Comment: The value for `temp` is in an object. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: temp is not in weather ... its an object of main

Comment: take a look at this, [generated model for openweathermap](https://github.com/romainmenke/Jenerator/blob/master/examples/openweather/openweathermap.swift) It might save you some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it should be

```
if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary {
    let temp = main["temp"] as! String
    print(temp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your example I now understand the logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:
`let temp = json["temp"] as? String`

Try this:

```
if let main = json["main"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let temp = main[temp]?.stringValue
    print(temp)

    //alternatively you can try this as per your convenience of data type
    let tempNew = main[temp]?.doubleValue
    print(tempNew) 
}
```