# All possible attributes in foursquare venue api

Tags: swift, parsing, foursquare

Looking for a list of **attributes** from the Foursquare venue API?

API call in question: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3

Thank you!

Comment: Please answer these questions so that we can better assist you:

1) Which language/framework are you using to access the API?

2) What have you tried? 

3) How are you storing the response? (As a String, as an object, etc.)

Comment: Coding in Swift. Have looked at many different API calls but have not come across an official list of attributes, thus the question.

Comment: I also need those... any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an exhaustive list posted anywhere - probably because the list is always evolving.

A good starting point may be to look at the attributes shown as filters in the Foursquare app, that is probably the most updated list.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create logic that parses the JSON attributes from the API response. This thread provides a good example that you can follow:

[Swift JSON parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594119/swift-json-parsing?s=1|2.8615)

Comment: Maybe my initial message is not clear, I have no issues retrieving the information from the JSON. I can query foursquare for their list of categories, but this is not possible for their list of attributes. I am looking for  a list, that's all.